# How to extract the img src content from a text in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following string in a variable in Ruby.

```
"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\" style=\"height:533px; width:800px\" /></p>\r\n"
```

I want to extract only the src content, that is:

```
"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\"
```

In Ruby how can I extract the text from the `src` attribute?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The line you show as what you want to extract (`"/ckeditor...jpg\"`)needs a non-escaped double quote at the end to match the one at the beginning. You need to either add one (or the more likely, I suspect) change the escaped quote at the end to an non-escaped quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a html/xml parser, in ruby [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is a great choice.  Example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = "<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\" style=\"height:533px; width:800px\" /></p>\r\n"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
src = doc.xpath("//img")[0]['src']
```

In this example, xpath is used to extract all  nodes, the first one is chosen, and then the 'src' attribute is returned as a string.

Comment: short n sweet n bang on target !

Comment: Somehow this seems like using a sledgehammer to drive a tack.

Comment: @Ajay although you accepted this, take a look at Arup's answer.  It uses a parser which is in the standard library so it might be more convenient :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland it depends - for one-off hacks a regex will do, but html is pretty complex so using a parser is almost always the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Tim I agree, but Doesn't seem like the OP is implementing a complex feature, just needs something small. However, I agree with you that if they were implementing html parsing over and over, I would use a html parsing library.

Comment: I like this solution better.  I'm trying to get the src for an attached image inside trim-content (ActionText)...which is not a self closing img tag.  REXML::Document cant handle the non self closing tag...nokogiri does.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick...

```
test = '"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\" style=\"height:533px; width:800px\" /></p>\r\n"'
src  = /src=\\"(.*?)\\"/.match(test)

puts src[1] # outputs /ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg
```

For the proper explanation:

1.) it looks for `src=\"` (we have to escape `\` with `\\`).

2.) once it finds it, `(.*?)` grabs everything until the next match.

3.) the next match is `\"` (again we have to escape `\` with `\\`).

The `.match` method of the Regexp class returns a hash. In this case the first index is the string you tested. The second index of your hash will contain your result.

OR if you don't like the looks of regular expressions and would much rather using css selectors, [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)'s css method can help you.

```
require 'nokogiri'

test = "<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\" style=\"height:533px; width:800px\" /></p>\r\n"

html = Nokogiri::HTML(test)
html.css("img").attribute('src').to_s # outputs /ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`REXML::Document`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Document.html)

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = REXML::Document.new("<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg\" style=\"height:533px; width:800px\" /></p>\r\n") 
doc.get_elements('//p/img')[0].attribute('src').to_s
# => "/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg"
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer, since rexml (which I didn't know about!) is in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the string between `src` and `style` I would use this:

```
text[/src=\"(.*)\"\sstyle=\"/,1]
  #=> "/ckeditor_assets/pictures/35/content_raw_lemon_cheesecake.jpg"
```

I've assumed you don't want the escaped double-quote at the end that you show in your desired output, but if you do, change the regex to:

```
/src=\"(.*)\sstyle=\"/
```

Comment: I like that you don't use a dependency!

Comment: @Seth, I am not familiar with the term 'dependency' as it relates to regexes.  Please explain.

Comment: adding in an external library. `require 'some-library-to-help-out'`.