# How to get src with gsub?(how to extract something in the pattern?)

Tags: ruby, gsub

I want to extract src in the text+tag string. For example, if the text is

```
hello <img src='address1'> hello2 <img src='address2'>hello3
```

I want to extract `address1` and `address2` with `gsub`.

If I code like this:

```rb
text = "hello <img src='address1'> hello2 <img src='address2'>hello3"
temp = text.gsub(/.*<img src=/,'').gsub(/>.*/,'')
```

I can get only `address2` (I mean the last address). I want to extract `address1` and `address2`, and do each to check in my DB.

Comment: StackOverflow allows you to preview your question before posting it. Unless you put HTML tags within code blocks, StackOverflow will not render them, so it looked like you just had a string "hello hello2 hello3" and were expecting to get the output "address1 address2", which was very confusing. I edited your post so it makes sense now. Please always try to make it as easy as possible for people to help you successfully -- previewing your questions to see if they look right and using nice formatting like code blocks will help with that.

Comment: Couple questions: what do you mean "do each to check in my DB"? Also, `gsub` is used to replace substrings, but you say you want to extract substrings. What exactly do you want the result to be? You say you want `address1` and `address2`. Does that mean you want an array consisting of those two strings? `gsub` won't return you an array of anything, it will just return a modified version of the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the img src content from a text in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651733/how-to-extract-the-img-src-content-from-a-text-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "hello <img src='address1'> hello2 <img src='address2'>hello3" 

str.scan(/(?<=<img src=')[\w ]+/)
  #=> ["address1", "address2"]
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan). The regular expression reads, "match one or more word characters (English letters, digits and the underscore) or spaces, immediately preceded by the string `"<img src='"`, `(?<=<img src=')` being a *positive lookbehind*.

Comment: I appreciate it. I solved this problem with split and array, but I would try this scan method.